# Determine if keystore type is pkcs12 or jks (programmatically)

Tags: java, keystore

Is there an easy way to determine the keystore type in java? The keystore file does not have an extencion but i know it may be either jks or pkcs12.

At the moment im using something like this:

```
public static boolean isJks(File f) throws Exception{   
    KeyStore ks = null;

    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        ks.load(fis, null);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(fis != null){
            fis.close();
        }
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(fis, null);
        return false;
    } finally {
        if(fis != null){
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a easier way of doing this? If not then is this the way to go or should it be improved?

Comment: Do you need to determine its type or do you need to load it? A possible improvement to you code is to change the return type to `String` instead of `boolean` and return the detected keystore type ("JKS", "pkcs12", etc).

Comment: I remember there is another type, which is `jceks`

Comment: I only need to know its type but i didn't know if that could be done without loading it. I know that it can be either jks or pkcs12 - no other types are possible in my case. 
Also i don't know its password so i used null. It seemed to work ( did not throw an exception, but if password i entered was not null and was wrong i got an exception). Dont know if using null password can cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth mentioning for those who come across this question in future. If you need to know the KeyStore type only in order to load it, it is easier post-[JDK-8062552](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8062552). You can simply specify the type as JKS and this will let you load both JKS and PKCS12 KeyStores. See example below:

```
private KeyStore loadKeyStore(String file, String password) {
    KeyStore keyStore;
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
    } catch (IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return keyStore;
}
```

However, if you load your KeyStore like this, `keystore.getType()` will always return `JKS`. So even if now you can read the KeyStore, you still won't know what was its type.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239875/jks-bks-and-pkcs12-file-formats) answer. Basically, for JKS keystore you can check the magic number which is a few bytes in the beginning of the file. The expected magic value is `0xFEEDFEED`. For PKCS12 it is not an easy thing to do, but you can check if the file is ASN1 structure, although potentially there could be other file formats based on ASN1, so your approach with loading a keystore may actually be the better one.